# How to include user has_many association on sign in response from devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

hope you guys are doing well,

I have this User which has a has_many association with an Address model (User has_many addresses). How can I config devise to return all the user addresses at the sign in?

The association already works well, but I cant seem to find a simple solution to this rather than doing another request to get the addresses info from the user, or maybe overriding devise sessions controller. (which I didnt try because I dont know how to exactly do without messing up the default config)

UPDATE: I am using devise token auth to handle the sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by implementing the answer found in this issue:https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/597#issuecomment-291893591

## user.rb

```
def token_validation_response                                                                                                                                         
    self.as_json(include: :addresses)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise::SessionsController#create looks like this:

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController

  # ...

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```

`respond_with` is a method from the [responders gem](https://github.com/heartcombo/responders) and actually generates the response. The simplest way would be to just override the method but you could also create you own responder which is covered in the readme.

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  private
  
  def respond_with(resource, **options)
    return super unless action_name == 'create'
    # generate whatever response you want
  end
end
```

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: 'my_sessions'
}
```

Comment: It is returning 401 code when I try to voerride using your code... The difference is just on routes.rb that instead of setting the controller for devise_for, i am doing it so for mount_devise_auth_token_for